# How to hide the Repeated record in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Using this query:

```
SELECT 
       linerbltbl.billofladingid, 
       linerbltbl.grossweighttotal, 
       linerb‌​ltbl.netweighttotal, 
       linerblwisecontainerdetailstbl.containertype, 
       linerblwisecont‌​ainerdetailstbl.cont‌​ainernumber, 
       linerblwisecontainerdetailstbl.sealnumber, 
       linerblwisecontain‌​erdetailstbl.princip‌​lecharge 
FROM   linerbltbl, 
       linerblwisecontainerdetailstbl 
WHERE  linerbltbl.shippername IS NOT NULL 
       AND linerbltbl.billofladingid = 
           linerblwisecontainerdetailstbl.bil‌​lofladingid
```

See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Guqv4.png) image.  It shows what my output *IS* and what I would like it to be.

You will note that the repeated data is blanked out.  Is there a way to do this in my query?

Comment: `select distinct * from table` ?

Comment: Sorry that time i have some problem occur with upload the image.now please check the image \

Comment: Please **do not** post images of code or sample data. Add formatted sample input and expected output along with the logic behind it. Also, post what you've tried so far.

Comment: Are you sure this is a SQL question and not a SSRS question?

Comment: I try this select LinerBLTbl.BillOfLadingID,LinerBLTbl.GrossWeightTotal,LinerBLTbl.NetWeightTotal,
LinerBLWiseContainerDetailsTbl.ContainerType,LinerBLWiseContainerDetailsTbl.ContainerNumber, 
LinerBLWiseContainerDetailsTbl.SealNumber,LinerBLWiseContainerDetailsTbl.PrincipleCharge
from LinerBLTbl,LinerBLWiseContainerDetailsTbl where LinerBLTbl.ShipperName is not null and
LinerBLTbl.BillOfLadingID=LinerBLWiseContainerDetailsTbl.BillOfLadingID

Comment: but in it all data is in same row but only last four column result is different

Comment: Put code in the question, not comments.

Comment: Your formatting is not a part of mysql or sql in general, you need to format it in your UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think you are going about this wrong.  While you CAN do this from within the query itself (see [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a6e97408-aa97-48ec-a559-b9071068432b/how-to-write-a-sql-statement-which-can-hide-duplicate-values-during-query-output?forum=transactsql) page) you are probably better off doing it in whatever is *consuming* the output.  For example, if you are taking this data and pasting it into MS Excel, you could check out [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/a-quick-trick-for-hiding-duplicate-excel-values/) post which does is via conditional formatting.  If you are consuming it from inside code, you can add logic to handle it there (since I don't know what you are going to do with it, it's hard to add any examples).

But, if you insist on doing it from within SQL it's going to be something to this effect (borrowing from the linked example):

```
;with t as
(SELECT 
       linerbltbl.billofladingid,
       linerbltbl.grossweighttotal, 
       linerb‌​ltbl.netweighttotal, 
       linerblwisecontainerdetailstbl.containertype, 
       linerblwisecont‌​ainerdetailstbl.cont‌​ainernumber, 
       linerblwisecontainerdetailstbl.sealnumber, 
       linerblwisecontain‌​erdetailstbl.princip‌​lecharge 
FROM   linerbltbl, 
       linerblwisecontainerdetailstbl 
WHERE  linerbltbl.shippername IS NOT NULL 
       AND linerbltbl.billofladingid = 
           linerblwisecontainerdetailstbl.bil‌​lofladingid
)
SELECT
    CASE WHEN RR = 1 THEN billofladingid ELSE '' END BillOfLadingID,
    CASE WHEN RR = 1 THEN grossweighttotal ELSE '' END GrossWeight,
    CASE WHEN RR = 1 THEN netweighttotal ELSE '' END NetWeight,
    containertype,
    cont‌​ainernumber,
    sealnumber,
    princip‌​lecharge
FROM
    (SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY billofladingid ORDER BY billofladingid, grossweighttotal)) [RR], *
     FROM t) SUBQUERY1
```